# how to fetch the 3 objects data based on the picklist values

Tags: apex

i have 3 objects

- employee-it contains picklist(low,medium,high)
- department
- location

how to filter the soql query based on picklist value

```
SELECT Id, Name, Employee__r.Branch__c, Employee__r.Name__c FROM Department__c
```

Comment: What you're asking is not very clear. Why is there a "Location" object? What is the name of the pick list field? How will the pick list value be provided? If you provide those details it'll be easier to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have created a MD relationship between two objects there exist a parent child relationship. The object on which you created the master detail field in the child, while the other object which you choose in the 2nd step of creating the MD field is the parent.
Based on the query Employee looks like your parent and Department your child. But it doesn't look right logically. Department should be the parent because 1 department can have many employees and 1 employee can have only 1 department as its parent.
Moving ahead assuming, based on your query example, that employee is the parent and department is the child.

The query for filtering low priority value should be

```
SELECT Id, Name, Employee__r.Branch__c, Employee__r.Name__c 
FROM Department__c 
WHERE Employee__r.priority__c = 'Low'
```

Basically you need to access the parent's filed using the `__r.FIELDNAME` and then use it in your WHERE clause at the end of SOQL.

You have not mentioned as to even how the object **Location** is related to the other two objects. Hence cant help on that.

Hope the answer helped you.